# How to handle wildcard in a raw string in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a script I run daily to compile a bunch of spreadsheets into one.  Well after a year of running one of the filenames changed due to it being produced 14 seconds later.  I read the filename in like this

```
uproduction = Path(r"\\server\folder\P"+year+month+day+r"235900.xls")

and then df = pd.read_excel(upreduction)
```

This was working fine until the file name changed to P20210225235914.xls .  When I am using a raw string like that is there a way I can make it pick any file that starts with P20210225*.xls ?  I can't seem to find exactly what i'm looking for for in the docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `glob`:

```
from glob import glob
glob(r"\\server\folder\P"+year+month+day+"*.xls")
```

Comment: I get ['\\\\server\\folder\\P20210225235914.xls'] returned and I'm not entirely sure how to get it back to \\server\folder\filename.xls

Comment: `glob` returns a list of string literals. Since backslash has a special meaning in Python strings, it needs to be escaped unless you are using raw strings. The string  \\ represents a single backslash. The upshot is that you can use `'\\\\server\\folder\\P20210225235914.xls'` in `Path()` as is, without any changes. By the way, the answer of @mullinscr will work too. Previously there was a mistake in it, which is why it got downvoted, but it is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the glob method on the Path:

```py
for file in Path(r'\\server\folder\').glob(r'P20210225*.xls'):
    print(file.name)
```